# Read external file on c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, object

I have this:

```
string StudentRegister::ReadDataFromFile(){
try{
    char c;
    int field = 1;
    vector<char> tmpVector;
    vector<Student> tmpStudentVector;
    char tmp[] = {'a'};
    CustomString studentCode(tmp, 1), secondName(tmp, 1), firstName(tmp, 1);
    Student student(studentCode, firstName, secondName);

    ifstream file1("Students.txt", ios::in);      
    if (!file1) throw MyExceptions();

    while(!file1.eof()){
        file1.get(c);
        if (c == '\n'){
                char *firstNameArray = new char[tmpVector.size()];
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < tmpVector.size(); i ++) firstNameArray[i] = tmpVector.at(i);

                CustomString firstName1(firstNameArray, tmpVector.size());
                firstName.setCandidateString(firstName1.getCandidateString(), tmpVector.size());
                firstName.setNumberOfChars(tmpVector.size());
             //   firstName.PrintData();
                tmpVector.clear();

                field = 1;
                Student student(studentCode, firstName, secondName);
                tmpStudentVector.push_back(student);
                //firstName.~CustomString();                   
        }else if (c == ','){
            if (field % 3 == 1){
                char *studentCodeArray = new char[tmpVector.size()];
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < tmpVector.size(); i ++) studentCodeArray[i] = tmpVector.at(i);

                CustomString studentCode1(studentCodeArray, tmpVector.size());
                studentCode.setCandidateString(studentCode1.getCandidateString(), tmpVector.size());
                studentCode.setNumberOfChars(tmpVector.size());
             //   studentCode.PrintData();
                tmpVector.clear();
            }else if (field % 3 == 2){
                char *secondNameArray = new char[tmpVector.size()];
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < tmpVector.size(); i ++) secondNameArray[i] = tmpVector.at(i);

                CustomString secondName1(secondNameArray, tmpVector.size());
                secondName.setCandidateString(secondName1.getCandidateString(), tmpVector.size());
                secondName.setNumberOfChars(tmpVector.size());
               // secondName.PrintData();
                tmpVector.clear();
            }
            field++;
        }else if (c != ','){
            tmpVector.push_back(c); 
            if (file1.eof()){
                char *firstNameArray = new char[tmpVector.size()];
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < tmpVector.size(); i ++) firstNameArray[i] = tmpVector.at(i);
                CustomString firstName1(firstNameArray, tmpVector.size());
                int len = tmpVector.size();
                firstName.setCandidateString(firstName1.getCandidateString(), tmpVector.size());
                firstName.setNumberOfChars(tmpVector.size());
                Student student(studentCode, firstName, secondName);
                tmpStudentVector.push_back(student);
            }
        }
    }


    for ( int i = 0; i < tmpStudentVector.size(); i ++)  tmpStudentVector.at(i).PrintData();
}catch(MyExceptions e){

}


}
```

Theses are the records from a txt file:

```
SR000001,EPONYMO 0001,ONOMA 0001
SR000002,EPONYMO 0002,ONOMA 0002
SR000003,EPONYMO 0003,ONOMA 0003
```

This is Student class:

```
class Student {
public:
  Student(CustomString &, CustomString &, CustomString &);  //Constructor
  Student(const Student &); //Copy Constructor    
  void setFirstName(CustomString  &); //FirstName Setter
  void setSecondName(CustomString &); //SecondName Setter
  void setCode(CustomString &); //Code Setter
  CustomString getCode(); //Code Getter
  CustomString getFisrtName(); //FirstName Getter
  CustomString getSecondName(); //SecondName Getter
  CustomString PrintData(); //Print Data Method 
  void operator= (const Student &); //Overloads the = method
  ~Student(); //Destructor
private:        
    CustomString &FirstName; //FirstName property
    CustomString &SecondName; //SecondName property
    CustomString &Code;//Code property
};
```

Finally this is the MyCustomStringClass:

```
class CustomString{
public:
  CustomString(char *, int);  //Constructor
  CustomString(); //Constructor
  CustomString(const CustomString &); //Copy Constructor
  char *getCandidateString(); //CandidateString Getter
  void setCandidateString(char *, int); //CandidateString Setter
  void setNumberOfChars(int); //Set the Number Of Chars
  int getNumberOfChars(); //Get the NumberOfChars
  char *strNCpy(char *, char *, int); //Strncpy() implementation      
  CustomString strNCpy(int); //Overload Strncpy() implementation
  int findFirstOf(char *, int); //Find_first_of() implementation
  bool operator== (const CustomString &) const; //Overload the == operator
  void operator= (const CustomString &); //Overload the = operator
  bool operator< (const CustomString &) const; //Overload the < operator
  bool operator!= (const CustomString &) const;//Overload the != operator
  int str_len (char *); //Strlen() implementation 
  void PrintData(); //Print CandidateString 
  //int str_len (); //Overload Strlen() implementation      
  //CustomString AppendCharsToCandidateString(char *); //Append chars to CandidateString
  //CustomString AppendCharsToCandidateString(vector<char>); //Append chars to CandidateString
 ~CustomString(); //Destructor
private:
  char *CandidateString; //CandidateString property
  int NumberOfChars; //Number of Chars
 };

 #endif /* CUSTOMSTRING_H */
```

As you see I shouldn't use any string or string.h method. When I run it I get the following :

```
CODE=SR000003 FirstName=ONOMA 00033 SecondName=EPONYMO 0003CODE=SR000003 FirstName=ONOMA 00033 SecondName=EPONYMO 0003CODE=SR000003 FirstName=ONOMA 00033 SecondName=EPONYMO 0003Destroying Object
```

It seems I can;t reinstatiate the Student object inside the class and I can't find a sollution on this.
Any suggestion?

Comment: what di dyou see when you stepped through with your debugger

Comment: Have you reviewed existing examples of reading a CSV file?  Search the internet for "c++ read file csv".

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` than character arrays a pointers.  You'll be thankful you did.

Comment: It's an assignment without using strings or relative methods, only pointers...